# After update libreoffice wont start

Tags: updates, libreoffice

Updated Ubuntu gnome 16.04 this week and libreoffice will not run from it's icon or CLI. Since my .deb libreOffice package died, I installed using the libreoffice snap and the snap package works. Now i have two libreoffice packages installed a .deb and a snap. Snap works .deb does not. updated kernal to 4.10.0-35-generic. 
Would like to use the .deb because the it looks better then the snap. Think my theme wasn't applied to the snap.
Snap build : libreoffice-5.3.4.2-snap1
deb build  : 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2

Comment: What error message do you get runnng libreoffice ?

Comment: I don't receive any error messages the mouse icon spins and nothing happens. even when ran at cli. Is there log files that would have the errors?

Comment: went to ~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/uno_packages/cache/log.txt all it had was this. ###### Progress log entry 2017-05-29 16:47:08 ######
###### Progress log entry 2017-05-30 10:54:57 ######
###### Progress log entry 2017-06-05 00:22:29 ######
###### Progress log entry 2017-06-05 11:38:34 ######
###### Progress log entry 2017-06-08 19:37:52 ######

Comment: Maybe a reinstall of the .deb package will fix?

Comment: .deb ? why not use the version in the repos ?

Comment: did a sudo apt-get install libreoffice updated libreoffice to 5.4 but still wont run. Maybe i'll uninstall purge and then reinstall

Comment: I would try a purge

Comment: apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
apt-get clean
apt-get autoremove ------- apt-get install libreoffice reintalled no problem but still wont launch

Comment: Sounds like time to file a bug report

Comment: it works. Had to reboot. Now deb package launches with theme too. Everything back to normal.

Comment: apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*  -------- apt-get clean --------apt-get autoremove ------ apt-get install libreoffice ------reboot

Comment: Thanks for advice thought there would of been a way to fix it rather than reinstalling. Linux FTW

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked from me,

```
apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
apt-get clean
apt-get autoremove
apt-get install libreoffice
reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with LibreOffice v5.4.1.2. I cleared

- `~/.config/libreoffice/4/cache/*`,
- `~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/uno_packages/cache/*`, and
- the `.lock` file

and it works fine for now.

Comment: Can a system update corrupt the cache folder?  Does the cache directory have any config files?  Don't understand how something in the cache folder could prevent libreoffice from starting up and running.

Comment: @m0ng00se very common situation when new software stops to understand old version cache, or cache become very big or smth like this. For me that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command:

```
sudo  apt --fix-broken install
```

Then, to clean up old packages, use this command:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```